# How do I click bottom links of Stack Overflow pages when editing answers?

Tags: bug

How do I click the bottom links of Stack Overflow pages when I am editing my answers?

This is what happens when scrolling down while editing your answers:

[image: Stack Overflow bottom links covered]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They left those boxes able to overlap the footer because they decided they were more important than the links in the footer and tweaking the sidebar to prevent that overlap [wasn't worth the time and effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236369).

So, if you want to click the links below those boxes, you'll just need to visit another page on the site that doesn't have those boxes that follow you at the right.